# Docusign Envelope Corrected - As a result, you no longer have access

Tags: docusignapi

I've been working with a docusign integration into our own application for a while, and recently I've started encountering a new error that I've never experienced before. I create a docusign envelope using Docusign's own interface, add my recipients, set up the signing fields, and then click send.

An email goes out to the users with a link for them to sign the document, as expected. But simultaneously, there is another email that says the following:

> [My User] has corrected [My Document].
> As a result, you no longer have access.

I click on the link for signing the document, and it results in the following:

[image]

In theory, this makes sense. If an envelope is edited or corrected, then the previous links are no longer valid. However, the envelope is never being corrected. It is created and sent in a single action. There isn't even time for a correction to be made. I'm the only person with access to the account, so no one else can be making corrections to the envelope. Additionally, this only seems to occur for certain recipients. Some recipients are fine, and this correction thing doesn't occur. For others, it happens and breaks the entire chain.

What could be causing Docusign to do this? I'm working with a developer account if that makes any difference. The only recent change that was made to my configuration is the addition of Connect with HMAC signatures to verify the validity of docusign responses back to my application. Even so, most of the time things seem to work exactly as intended and expected.

Comment: can you share your code? do you use recipient auth?

Comment: I don't use recipient auth directly. I have the following setting configured for Recipient Authentication Settings under Security Settings in the admin:
"the sender can require that a recipient must authenticate on any envelope sent from this account"

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @CurtisSnowden, were you able to resolve this issue? One of my QA people is running into the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I never did. I looked around extensively and could not find anything that could help me explain what happened. Interesting that you say QA. The problem on our end was QA as well. As far as I'm aware, we've never once had a problem in Production, even when using the same email addresses. Is your problem also with the Development API? Perhaps there's a bug in that specifically?